# How to Delete Attachments in Outlook Meetings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How do I delete attachments in Outlook meetings?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you open the meeting, left click the attachment to select it and then press the delete key. You then click save and close button, and viola, it is gone.

Comment: This works with email, but not with meetings.  Did you actually try it?

Comment: Yes as I wrote the answer above - it works. I have a highly constrained (sizewise) outlook mailbox @ work. I have to do this quite often as PM's are always sending huge attachments with their meeting invites.